# Calculating area of polygon intersection with condition

Tags: qgis, geometry, intersection, area

Layer 1 consists of 3 features with different values assigned to them (10 or 20). Feature from Layer 2 overlaps all 3 of them. I'm looking to calculate intersection area with polygons but only with ones that have value 10 assigned to them.
 Here is a catch, I want it done only using expression calculator without processing tools.
Here is a thread that I found that is somewhat close to what I'm trying to do: [Using the field calculator to calculate intersections](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384717/using-the-field-calculator-to-calculate-intersections).
I'm using QGIS 3.20.1 
Update: I've managed to calculate the area of polygon intersection using:
`area(intersection($geometry,aggregate('Layer_1','collect',$geometry)))`
 but it still lacks `value = 10` condition

[image: Visualization]

Comment: start by selecting polygons with the required value, then do the intersection

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as I stated in the question I don't want to use processing tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an [`overlay_intersect()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-intersects) function for that, as it contains an (optional) filter argument:

```
area(
    intersection (
        $geometry, 
        collect_geometries(
            overlay_intersects ('layer1',$geometry, filter:=value=10)
        )
    )
)
```

*Using the expression from above without the `area()` function in Geometry Generator, you can create the intersection (red) of features from layer 1 (blue) and value=10 with the polygon from layer 2 (yellow) for visual control of what you are calculating the area:*

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This expression appears to be working just fine:

```
area(
    intersection(
        $geometry,
         aggregate(
             'Layer_1',
             'collect',
             $geometry,
              "Value" = 10
            )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I got weird results from the one above, this isolates the return value for `"value"=20` out and the return values are more accurate.

```
case
when "Value"=10 --this can be changed, but for this case it works
then
area(
    intersection(
        $geometry,aggregate(
            layer:='Layer_1',
            aggregate:='collect',
            expression:=$geometry,
            filter:="Value"=20 AND --could also use not equal to 10
                intersects(
                    $geometry,
                    geometry(@parent)
                )
            )
    )
)
else 0
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by weird results ? Can you please elaborate, ? Also I can't get your expression to work, I think it might be because in the part `when "Value"=10` you are trying to refer to attribute from Layer 1 while doing calculations on Layer 2.