# Why area of intersection differs from total area of polygon?

Tags: qgis, polygon, intersection, area

I calculated intersection between Layer 1 and Layer 2 using expression below:

```
area(
    intersection (
        $geometry, 
        collect_geometries(
            overlay_intersects ('layer1',$geometry)
        )
    )
)
```

And total area of polygon on Layer 2 using: `$area` 
Given the fact that polygon drawn on Layer 2 is completely inside polygon from Layer 1 the area of intersection should equal the total area of polygon but for some reason that's not the case and I don't understand why and how to fix it.

[image: Geometry situation]

[image: Attribute table]

This question is a indirect follow-up to this thread: [Calculating area of polygon intersection with condition](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448930/calculating-area-of-polygon-intersection-with-condition/448936#448936)

Comment: Probably one calculation was done using planimetric measuring, and the other took into account the ellipsoid.

Comment: So it has something to do with CRS or with the way both funtions are calculated? I made sure that both Layers and Project are using EPSG:2180, but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: Also check this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/348856/63384 for the difference between planimetric area `area()` and ellipsoidal area `$area`

Comment: and also this one of course : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/calculating-polygon-areas-in-shapefile-using-qgis

Comment: @ahmadhanb This is what I was looking for, I should be using area($geometry) instead of $area. Please copy your comment as answer so I can accept it as solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in my comment, check [Using area() or $area function in QGIS, when the data (polygon) is stored in UTM?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/348856/63384) for the difference between planimetric area `area()` and ellipsoidal area `$area` for more information.